# Getting Error for asynchronous API call (v2.3) through postman

Tags: rest-api

I get valid response when I try Synchronous API call.

E.g.

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://10.xx.xx.xxxx/rest/V1/customers' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer jz62fwxwkdyyat8qeuxl1XXXXX97lpz' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
"customer":
    {
        "email": "user@gmail.com",
        "firstname":"user",
        "lastname":"demo"
    },
    "password":"Welome@1234"
}'
```

But when I try the same payload with async call. I get below error

```
{
    "message": "Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log file. Report ID: webapi-5e26c6cc757f3"
}
```

I am not able to find Magento log file. Please let me know how can we resolve this?

And, why am I getting error for correct payload?

Comment: Just run the below command in magento root directory, it will show that log file location.

grep -r "Report ID: webapi-5e26c6cc757f3" var/              it would probably in exception.log . And add log here so that we can help you out